# Excel Arrange multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I have a data like this in excel:

```
1 1
1 2
2 2
3 2
```

And I want the result to be displayed like this:

```
1
1
  1
2
  2
  2
  2
3
```

Its like a ascending sorting. If the number in columnA <= columnB, it will be display first, at the same time, columnB will have a empty cell or blank value.
I have looked for this for a while but no one has the problem like this.
I would prefer a formula rather than VBA code.
Please advise, thanks!

Edit: I hope this explanation will be easier to understand

Data (A1:B2) - Result (C1:D4). Each number in Data (A1:B2) is a result of complicated formula so I cannot change its position

```
  A B  C D
1 1 2  1
2 3 4    2
3      3
4        4
```

Comment: your explanation should be clearer on which transformations are used to go from your input to your output. For now it doesn't match

Comment: Has **anyone** posted a question showing original effort today?

Comment: I added some details to this problems, if you guys cannot understand then I guess I have a very bad explanation skill

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you want to avoid VBA, here's a manual process that would give you the results you want:

1. Color each column (ie. Column A `Red` and Column B `Blue`)
2. Place values of column B under column A
3. Sort & Filter by `Sort Smallest to Largest`
4. Copy the contents of column A to column B
5. Last for Column A Find and `Replace all`* with format `Blue` then do the same for column B only with format `Red`. (See below for more info on how to do that).

Following those steps isn't the most conventional, but it will give you the results you wanted without VBA.

***Find and Replace based on font color:**
1. Press `Ctrl-H`
2. Click `Options`
3. Click `Format` > `Font` > then select your font color > `OK`
4. With the `Find What` blank with the font color and the `Replace With` blank click `Replace All`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will work on a formula base on this manual process ideal